# Installing boost log

Tags: boost, module, installation, logging, boost-log

I've got [this](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation.html) library for logging in boost. I have a question about installing. How to install it? Here is the latest [version](http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_boost-log/releases/?file_id=2574573). There are 3 folder: boost, doc, libs. How can I install this library without recompiling all boost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest case you need to do 2 things: add /boost to your compiler include search path, and add all *.cpp files from /libs/log/src to your project, compiling those together with your application.

Note: this will work properly as long as your application consists out of the main executable only. If you have additional shared libraries of your own (which also use Boost.Log) it might be the best to copy (or link) /boost and /libs into your Boost source tree and rebuild it from there.